# Can't load from AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained - TypeError: duplicate file name (sentencepiece_model.proto)

Tags: python, nlp, protocol-buffers, huggingface

I'm trying to load tokenizer and seq2seq model from pretrained models.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("ozcangundes/mt5-small-turkish-summarization")

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("ozcangundes/mt5-small-turkish-summarization")
```

But I got this error.

```
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py:1028, in FileDescriptor.__new__(cls, name, package, options, serialized_options, serialized_pb, dependencies, public_dependencies, syntax, pool, create_key)
   1026     raise RuntimeError('Please link in cpp generated lib for %s' % (name))
   1027 elif serialized_pb:
-> 1028   return _message.default_pool.AddSerializedFile(serialized_pb)
   1029 else:
   1030   return super(FileDescriptor, cls).__new__(cls)

    TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool: duplicate file name (sentencepiece_model.proto)
```

I tried updating or downgrading the protobuf version. But I couldn't fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue when trying to use the [microsoft/deberta-v3-small](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/deberta-v3-small) model. That is, at first it complained about not being able to find `protobuf`, and when I installed the latest, it asked for version `3.20.x`. The issue happened after I downgraded to the lower version.

Anyway, I was experimenting with it on a locally-running Jupyter notebook. Rerunning that cell didn't help. But when I chose to "Restart & Run All," the problem went away.

Therefore, to solve your issue, I believe that you need to restart the Python instance where it cached the latest version of `protobuf` in the first place.

##### Steps to reproduce:

1. ```py
   from transformers import AutoTokenizer

   tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("some_model")

   # outcome: some error asking for `protobuf`
   ```
2. ```bash
   pip install protobuf
   ```

   Rerun the code above; some error asking for `protobuf@3.20.x`
3. ```bash
   pip uninstall protobuf
   pip install protobuf==3.20
   ```

   Rerun the code above; same error as in OP
4. Restart the Python instance (notebook, app, etc.); ✓ no error

Answer (score 4):

ilyakam,

I ran into the same problem with mrm8488/t5-base-finetuned-wikiSQL, also in a notebook, in a virtual environment. Your solution did (almost) work, I had to add the line 'PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION="python"'

So in case your solution does not work 100%, try adding the line in the notebook

Andreas

python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: I found that downgrading protobuf immediately broke everything, however, the simple fix described above worked immediately when placed at the head of the Notebook - specifically it's `import os`
`os.environ["PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION"]="python"`   In my case the problematic model was "google/pegasus-cnn_dailymail", the only model (so far) to have this issue.